# How to charge 8S battery pack with two 4S BMS circuits?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, safety, series, bms

I recently made 8S battery pack out of 18650 cells (4.2V each) and I am worried about connecting it to BMS. Some time ago I asked what BMS should I get (well, I asked if i have to have some BMS at all -> I have to :-)) and I got some information that it is much cheaper to get two 4S BMSs than buying one 8S (which is true) and connect them in series. But it turned out that I am pretty unsure how exactly should I do so.

It would be impossible for me to explain my thoughts, so I am adding an image with schematic (hopefully it's readable). Is it correct or not?? Those 16,8V are meant for charging each 4S segment and 33,6V marks are supposed to be for battery pack output.

Not sure if it is necessary, but these are my BMS circuits:
[https://www.ebay.com/itm/234106510791?hash=item3681d5ddc7:g:PGsAAOSwL6dg~7IX](https://www.ebay.com/itm/234106510791?hash=item3681d5ddc7:g:PGsAAOSwL6dg%7E7IX)

[image: My schematic]

Comment: OK, so instead of single BMS for eight lithium cells, you now basically have two separate managed 4S packs that you must balance with another BMS that can handle two 4S packs in order to create a 8S pack. Being cheaper does not mean easier.

Comment: Just as a side note, two of those 4S BMS you linked to are more expensive than many of the 8S BMS boards. And the answer to your previous question did not tell you to connect packs in series and charge them simultaneously with 8S charger, but separately, with one 4S charger charging one half at a time, or connecting the 4S packs in parallel for charging them with single 4S charger.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Justme. The link for BMS circuit that i posted is just for ilustration. I didn’t get them from ebay, but from local market and thery were much cheaper.  Maybe I'm dump but I still don't get it. So I should just brek the connection between 4th and 5th cell to make 2 separate battery pack and then connect the BMSs outputs in series (P+ and P- -> charging and optional output)?